# Change color of logo from color 1 to color 2 back to color 1

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I use this code to change the color of `id="logo"` from white to green. But I want to change the color back to white when I have scrolled all the way down to the bottom of the site.

I have tried with else if but haven't got the else if function to work..

```js
const nav = document.querySelector('#logo');
  nav.className = 'blend'
  window.onscroll = () => {
    if(this.scrollY >= window.innerHeight-80) nav.className = 'color';
    else nav.className = 'blend';
  };
```

```css
.blend a{
  color: white;
}

.color a{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="logo" class="nav color">
  <a>LOGO</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The code work correctly. Check https://jsfiddle.net/wr4ds3j0/

Comment: It's hard to see with a white color but this code works

Comment: @Mohammad no - it doesn't go back to white when "scrolled all the way down to the bottom of the site"

Comment: You need to add a check for: `this.scrollY + window.innerHeight == document.documentElement.scrollHeight)` to see when it's at the bottom of the scroll

Comment: Oh yes, I think https://jsfiddle.net/mjw205xz/ is what OP want

Comment: Not also that `()=> { this` may not be what you're expecting.  In this case it's the `window`, which *is* what you're expecting, but not because it's from `window.onscroll`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17514482/2181514 point 8.

Comment: Here is a new fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/go2aw5yb/1/ i want the logo to be green on the when its white and back to white on the footer. But now i turns green and back to white to quick..

Comment: I think this is what you want https://jsfiddle.net/8xvap5f2/

Comment: @Mohammad Yes!!

Comment: It may be that intersectionObserver could help - it has the advantage that it's asynchronous, the browser worries about how best to implement it and you don't have to spend time doing things on every user bit of scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get distance of elements from top using [`offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) to detecting that scroll is between two elements.

```js
const nav = document.querySelector('#logo');
const back1 = document.querySelector('.background1');
const back2 = document.querySelector('.background2');

nav.className = 'blend'
window.onscroll = () => {
  if(back1.offsetTop+back1.offsetHeight < this.scrollY && this.scrollY < back2.offsetTop)
    nav.className = 'color';
  else 
    nav.className = 'blend';
};
```

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 200vh;
}

.background1{
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.background2{
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#logo{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
}
.blend a{
  color: white;
}
.color a{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="background1"></div>
<div id="logo" class="nav color">
  <a>LOGO</a>
</div>
<br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br>
<div class="background2"></div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
.
```